# Is there a secure asymmetric key storage built in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

The latest versions of operation systems became very good at protecting sensitive kernel data from leaking to third-party malicious applications. I would assume that Microsoft might have implemented a mechanism to securely store encryption keys at the kernel level.

I have heard about Microsoft CryptoAPI, but at a first glance it just seems like a Java CryptoAPI implementation for C++/C# with a "keystore" doesn't have too many advantages over storing encryption keys in plain old files (in terms of security). Am I missing something here?

---

My intended use case of such a mechanism would look something like this:

1. Ask Microsoft CryptoAPI to generate a new public-private keypair and
   store it in a secure storage in the OS.
2. Dump public key and send it to the remote server for signature checks.
3. When it's time to sign a message, just call Microsoft CryptoAPI to do it for me and return the result.

Just to sum it up - in the system, I need there should be absolutely no ways for users (even with admin permissions) to obtain the private key.

Is there any feature in Windows that is similar to what I have described?

Comment: *"The latest versions of operation systems became very good at protecting sensitive kernel data"* - Have you forgotten about [Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability))? It doesn't appear that Microsoft have released a patch that addresses all issues for all supported versions of the OS. Much as I like the Windows OS, this is currently a lost cause; the bug is baked into silicone, and we have to assume that the kernel is no longer safe, until all affected *hardware* has been replaced.

Comment: @IInspectable, I'm aware of Meltdown and Spectre vulnerabilities, though I think it takes much more effort and skill to exploit, compared to just stealing keys from the hard-drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They CryptoAPI necessarily stores keys on the filesystem. It uses ACLs to guard access, but those are no defence against a system administrator.

However CryptoAPI can work with smart cards and so on. i.e. "hardware" based private keys, which is really the only way that they keys are ultimately not going to be sitting somewhere on the filesystem.

Comment: ACLs only control permissions when accessing the filesystem on Windows. If you mount the filesystem on another system, it can (and usually does) ignore the ACLs. You can prevent filesystem access by using an encryption technology (like BitLocker). But that's not entirely safe either. As far as I know, BitLocker can be unlocked through brute force attacks.

Comment: If malicious people can steal the hard drive they can steal the hardware private key. Physical security is required around a private key.

Comment: An attacker does not necessarily need to have physical access here. Consider a dual-boot setup, where a user boots into Linux, that's running malicious software to read out the NTFS filesystem. Linux does not care about the ACLs.

Comment: The point is the filesystem is the only persistent storage available to any crypto store whatsoever that does not otherwise utilise specialised hardware.

Comment: Modern motherboards will have a TPM, so technically there is a non filesystem place for 'a' private key. That key 'could' be used to encrypt filesystem stored keys which would render them useless to anyone who did not also possess that physical TPM.

Comment: Well, I'm just trying to find a way to protect client authorization keys from malicious software (that in some cases could be run with admin permissions). For the sake of simplicity I would assume that nobody has physical access to the system

Comment: This is why, on servers, UAC should be kept on. In which case, malicious software could not be run with admin permissions. Outside of using dedicated hardware (like smart cards), the filesystem is the only local r/w persistent storage. i.e. if the private keys are not standalone files, they're in files somewhere, and just as accessible to malicious software.